# How to generate arguments to find command from array in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to look for several filenames, sometimes specifying wildcards in my input.
Below is the simplification of what I have. Assume that the `v` array will be generated from a file or whatever

```
#!/bin/bash
from_date=2020-05-17
to_date=2020-06-17
v=('-name "*a*"' '-o' '-name "*b*"')
find . "${v[@]}" -newermt "$from_date" ! -newermt "$to_date"
```

This yields the error:
`` find: unknown predicate `-name "*a*"' ``

Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea was right, but the quoting for the first argument is not. When you do `'-name "*a*"'`, the shell preserves that to be a single word which is "totally" fine from the array's perspective. But `find` command expects a predicate named `-name` and *not* `-name "*a*"`.

With the quoted expansion you have the shell passing the word `-name "*a*"` as one of the command options to `find` which it does not like. Separate the quoting of the arguments, so that they are passed separately.

```
v=('-name' '*a*' '-o' '-name' '*b*')
```